# Salesforce Einstein get dataflowjob status REST API

Tags: rest-api, rest, analytics, einstein

I was able to call a dataflow through REST API with the following:

Request: /services/data/v48.0/wave/dataflowjobs

Request Body: 
{
  "dataflowId": "02K2w0000009xxxxx",
  "command" : "start"
}

**Question is: How can I get the status of this dataflow job?**

I can get the status through this command /wave/dataflowjobs/[dataflowjobId here] but there's no way for me to get the dataflowjobId after triggering the dataflow.

Appreciate your response

Answer (score -1):

The dataflow job id should be in the response body after you start. Please see this article for more information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_run_schedule_sync_data.htm

Link to dataflow job id doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_dataflowjobs_id.htm#DataflowJobRepresentation